NetOffice from a windows service
I have a windows service that calls a batch file to execute a macro in a spreadsheet but when I call the open file method it always comes back with an error. If I run the batch file from the command line it works fine.
The error I get: is Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. I'm not sure if I have to configure something to run the batch file from the service.
        static void RunExcelMacro(string filePath, string macroName)
        {
            Workbook workbook = null;
            var excelApp = new Application { Visible = false };
            try
            {
            workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
                excelApp.Run(macroName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error running macro: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the workbook and release resources
                workbook.SaveAs($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)}\\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)}.xlsx",XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
                workbook.Close(false);
                excelApp.Quit();
                excelApp.Dispose();
            }
        }

The service code that runs the batch file is:
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"cmd /C \"{fullBatPath}\"",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Verb = "runas"
            }
        };
        process.Start();

